# Unable to config jenkins on mac

Tags: macos, jenkins

I have setup jenkins on mac.I could able to use it.

`How to start & stop jenkins server on mac` (localhost always reachable, probably, i might have installed it in some start service) ?

```
When i click on manage jenkins and configuration, it keeps on loading. Doesn't allow to edit it.

Jenkins ver. 2.60.3
```

Comment: did you check the log ?

Comment: @MorLajb : No, I haven't. where can i find it ?

Comment: look for the Jenkins home folder , and check the jenkins.log , another option is to open another gui and Manage Jenkins --> System log -- > All Jenkins logs

Comment: Thanks, got it. Timer task hudson.plugins.disk_usage.WorkspaceDiskUsageCalculationThread@5b868356 failed
java.lang.ClassCastException: jenkins.security.ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. How can i post huge logs here ?

Comment: Caught exception evaluating: h.filterDescriptors(it,attrs.descriptors) in /configure. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at hudson.model.DescriptorVisibilityFilter.apply(DescriptorVisibilityFilter.java:72)
 at hudson.Functions.filterDescriptors(Functions.java:1863)

Comment: Caught exception evaluating: h.filterDescriptors(it,attrs.descriptors) in /configure. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at hudson.model.DescriptorVisibilityFilter.apply(DescriptorVisibilityFilter.java:72)
 at hudson.Functions.filterDescriptors(Functions.java:1863)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor210.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: are you using the admin user ? or you disable the security ?

Comment: I haven't granted permission to any users yet. Yes, admin user now.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it isn't strictly related but it's worth to consider using Docker to run your Jenkins instance. It's realy simple and fits ideally for testing purposes (I suppose it's not your productions environment?).

https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/

Comment: Yes, it's not production environment. I'm using it for my local. Why docker here ?

Comment: Using docker you get environment independent configuration. You can just run prepared image and start working with Jenkins. It would help you avoid platform dependent issues and what's more you won't change your system configuration.

Comment: do i just need to install docker spearately ? is that enough ? are both jenkins and docker not related ?

Comment: Above link is redirecting to deprecated page.

Comment: @DieselKumar if you don't know Docker it's good idea to start with short introduction: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/ (linked in comments above). However to use Jenkins image you don't need vast knowledge. Still, it's worth to know how it works. 
(I fixed deprecated link.)

Answer (score 0):

> How to start & stop jenkins server on mac?

You can use below commands to stop & start jenkins on MAC OS -

stop - `sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist`

start - `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist`

For using docker, you can use `docker run` or the below docker-compose -

```
version: "3"

services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkinsci/jenkins
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
```

Comment: I didn't get this docker concept. can you help me here.

Comment: You may want to read more about docker - https://docs.docker.com/get-started/ . However you can start/stop jenkins using command provided above.